# How do I 'tell' R to read 0 and 1 values so that it does not error them as infinite?

Tags: r, logging, statistics, transformation

I am trying to construct a qq-plot for data transformed logarithmically.
This is the input:

> qqnorm(log(dframeA$Chocolate))
>   Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values

How do I solve this?

P.S. I am very new to the use of R.

Regards,
Kate.

Comment: Or `qqnorm(log(pmax(dframeA$Chocolate, 1)))`

Comment: > qqnorm(log(dframeA$Chocolate, ylim=c(0,1))
+ )
Error in log(dframeA$Chocolate, ylim = c(0, 1)) : 
  unused argument (ylim = c(0, 1))
>

Comment: qqnorm(log(pmax(dframeA$Chocolate, 1))) That works, :) thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably values of 0 in your `dframeA$Chocolate` variable. As there is no logarithm of the value 0, you probably need to use this in order to prevent an error message:

```
qqnorm(log(dframeA$Chocolate + 1))
```

The advantage is that the log of 1 is equal to 0. A zero before is still a zero after the transformation. As noted in the comments, this works only if `dframeA$Chocolate > -1`

Comment: It won't work if there is at least one `dframeA$Chocolate` < -1, let's say -2 or -3. `pmax` is a better option.